# PSTriks 3D spheres randomly distributed inside a torus

Tags: xetex, pstricks, pst-solides3d, pst-3dplot

I would like to randomly distribute "n" number of spheres (or spheroids) inside a torus. The code I used to generate the toroid is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\drawCircles{%
  \parametricplotThreeD[xPlotpoints=100](0,360)(0,360){%
    /k 2 def /k2 4 def
    t cos k mul 4 u sin k mul add mul
    t sin k mul 4 u sin k mul add mul
    u cos k2 mul
  }
  \parametricplotThreeD[yPlotpoints=100](0,360)(0,360){%
    /k 2 def /k2 4 def
    u cos k mul 4 t sin k mul add mul
    u sin k mul 4 t sin k mul add mul
    t cos k2 mul
  }
}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.75}
\begin{pspicture}(-28,-8)(28,8)
    \psset{Beta=10,Alpha=0,linewidth=0.1pt,linecolor=blue}
    \drawCircles
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I do it with PSTricks? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is a 3d object in parallel view without hidden lines, which makes it difficult to see the fron and back. It makes more sense to use package `pst-solides3d` instead. It can handle perspective view with hidden lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\drawCircles{%
    \parametricplotThreeD[xPlotpoints=100](0,360)(0,360){%
        /k 2 def /k2 4 def
        t cos k mul 4 u sin k mul add mul
        t sin k mul 4 u sin k mul add mul
        u cos k2 mul
    }
    \parametricplotThreeD[yPlotpoints=100](0,360)(0,360){%
        /k 2 def /k2 4 def
        u cos k mul 4 t sin k mul add mul
        u sin k mul 4 t sin k mul add mul
        t cos k2 mul
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \psset{unit=0.75}
    \begin{pspicture}(-15,-10)(15,10)
    \psset{Beta=30,Alpha=0,linewidth=0.1pt,linecolor=blue}
    \pstThreeDCoor[xMax=6,yMax=6,zMax=6]
    \drawCircles
    \pstThreeDSphere(0,8,0){4}
    \pstThreeDSphere(8,0,0){4}
    \pstThreeDSphere(0,-8,0){4}
    \pstThreeDSphere(-8,0,0){4}
    \end{pspicture}

    \begin{pspicture}(-15,-10)(15,10)
    \psset{Beta=30,Alpha=0,linewidth=0.1pt,linecolor=blue}
    \pstThreeDCoor[xMax=6,yMax=6,zMax=6]
    \pstThreeDSphere(0,8,0){4}
    \pstThreeDSphere(8,0,0){4}
    \pstThreeDSphere(0,-8,0){4}
    \pstThreeDSphere(-8,0,0){4}
    \drawCircles
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and for random values (here only for +/- x:

```
\pstThreeDSphere( rrand rand 17 mod 8 sub, dup \pst@number\psunit\space div dup mul 64 exch sub sqrt,0){4}
\pstThreeDSphere( rand 17 mod 8 sub, dup \pst@number\psunit\space div dup mul 64 exch sub sqrt,0){4}
\pstThreeDSphere( rand 17 mod 8 sub, dup \pst@number\psunit\space div dup mul 64 exch sub sqrt,0){4}
\pstThreeDSphere( rand 17 mod 8 sub, dup \pst@number\psunit\space div dup mul 64 exch sub sqrt,0){4}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would need a function that randomly draws "n" spheres of different sizes within the volume of the torus. With \psSolid I can't check the section of the torus (e.g. torus with elliptical and non-circular section).

Comment: See edited answer. However, for parallel projection it is difficult to decide, what is in front and what is in the back.